# Using User-Defined Variables in NamedQuery in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, named-query

I have task to load all products  in the categories (load by name) and sub categories. Having working with MySQL, I`ve created SQL query:

```
select *
from product
where primaryCategoryID in (
select  categoryID
from    (select * from category) categories,
        (select pv := (select categoryID from category where name = 'Tools') as ID) initialisation
where   find_in_set(parentCategory, pv) > 0
and     pv := concat(pv, ',', categoryID)
union 
select categoryID from category where name = 'Tools'
)
```

As you can mentioned 'Tools' in a name of category. It works well But if you have any suggestion(s) - you are more than welcome.
In my project I`m working with Hibernate, Named Query. And issue is with variable @pv. Now It is not compiled and throws exception as 'unexpected token...'
Does anyone know how to work with variable in NamedQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not support many SQL features. E.g. you use `union` in your query which is not supported. The same with variables.

Try to use Named Native Query (see [example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/))

For annotation it could be like this (from example above)

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "findStockByStockCodeNativeSQL",
    query = "select * from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode",
        resultClass = Stock.class
    )
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "mkyong")
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {
```

and place your query in the annotation

Comment: Thanks, It is useful comment. Issue is how to load all products in categories and its subcategories via Hivernate(Named-Query).

Comment: Post your entities and current code you have. In simple words you need to load category list (initial list by name), join child categories (don't know your parent-child mapping in the entities), and join products (again don't know your entity to provide correct mapping). It's fine for depth=1. If you need all categories subtree I am afraid hibernate won't provide a way to do this. So you can use native query and map them to desired entities.

Comment: Thank you alot. For 1-depth it works. So, question is open for case when the depth is more that 1(original issue). If Hibernate doesnt work with this query, what is your opinion about procedure/function? Does Hibernate can  load data via calling procedure/function?

Comment: You can use Named Native Query and place the working SQL as it was mentioned in the answer. It's the same as procedure